# when i start the fragment in slidemenu but getting error

Tags: android

please help

Submitcv.java
this is the fragment of navigation `slidemenu(submitcv)` but i have getting error when i execute the fragment from `mainactivity`.but when i used these fragment 
without any code it's executed
and logcat is nothing show any error

```
package com.example.app.slidemenu;
    import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
    import java.util.Calendar;
    import java.util.Locale;
    import com.example.app_placement.R;
    import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
    import android.app.DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener;
    import android.app.Fragment;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.text.InputType;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.AdapterView;
    import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.DatePicker;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.Spinner;

    public class Submit_resume extends Fragment implements OnClickListener
    {


    //    EditText name,emailid,dateofbirth,location,currentsalary,mobilenumber;
    //    RadioGroup gendergroup;
    //    RadioButton male,female;
    //    Button submitcv;

        Spinner spinner;
        String string_array[];
        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayadapter;
        EditText dateofbirth;
        private DatePickerDialog fromDatePickerDialog;
        private SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter;
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {

          View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.submit_resume, container, false);
    //      name=(EditText)container.findViewById(R.id.sname);
    //      emailid=(EditText)container.findViewById(R.id.sbtmail);
    //      dateofbirth=(EditText)container.findViewById(R.id.sdob);
    //      location=(EditText)container.findViewById(R.id.slocation);
    //      currentsalary=(EditText)container.findViewById(R.id.currentsalary);
    //      mobilenumber=(EditText)container.findViewById(R.id.smobile);
    //      gendergroup=(RadioGroup)container.findViewById(R.id.subgender);
    //      submitcv=(Button)container.findViewById(R.id.submitcv);
    //      Submit_cv();

          spinner=(Spinner)container.findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
            //dateofbirth=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.sdob);
            string_array=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.spinner_array);

            arrayadapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                  string_array);

             spinner.setAdapter(arrayadapter);
    //          Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    //          SimpleDateFormat ss = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    //          Date date = new Date();
    //          String currentdate= ss.format(date);
               // dob=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.sdob);
                //dob.setText(currentdate);

             spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                            int position, long id) { 
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                       // spin_val = gender[position];//saving the value selected


                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }

                });



             dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy", Locale.US);

             findViewsById();

                setDateTimeField();

          return rootView;

        }

        private void findViewsById()
        {
            dateofbirth = (EditText)getView().findViewById(R.id.sdob);  
            dateofbirth.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
            dateofbirth.requestFocus();


        }

        private void setDateTimeField() {
            dateofbirth.setOnClickListener(this);


            Calendar newCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            fromDatePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), new OnDateSetListener() {

                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                    Calendar newDate = Calendar.getInstance();
                    newDate.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
                    dateofbirth.setText(dateFormatter.format(newDate.getTime()));
                }

            },newCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), newCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), newCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));


        }



        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(v == dateofbirth) {
                fromDatePickerDialog.show();
            } 
        }

    //  public void Submit_cv()
    //    {
    //      
    //      System.out.println("value of usetname: "+name.getText().toString());
    //      
    //      final String gender = ((RadioButton)getView().findViewById(gendergroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId() )).getText().toString();
    //      System.out.println(gender);
    //    }


        }
```

mainactivity.java
this is mainactivity in which define slider code and also define all the fragment of slider.but when used is fragment with any code except initial fragment inflate method.I'm using anything in fragment
    package com.example.app_placement;

```
import info.androidhive.slidingmenu.adapter.NavDrawerListAdapter;
import info.androidhive.slidingmenu.model.NavDrawerItem;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.*;
import com.example.app.slidemenu.*;


@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    // Dialog choicedialog;


    ShareActionProvider mshareactioprovider;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    // nav drawer title
    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;

    // used to store app title
    private CharSequence mTitle;

    // slide menu items
    private String[] navMenuTitles;
    private TypedArray navMenuIcons;

    private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;
    private NavDrawerListAdapter adapter;
    private LinearLayout drawerll;

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        TextView userTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvsideUserName);

        System.out.println("value of user from db:"+Constants.USERNAME);
        userTextView.setText(Constants.USERNAME);
        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();

        // load slide menu items
        navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);

        // nav drawer icons from resources
        navMenuIcons = getResources()
                .obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);
        drawerll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerll);

        navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();

        // adding nav drawer items to array
        // Home
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[0], navMenuIcons
                .getResourceId(0, -1)));
        // Find People
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[1], navMenuIcons
                .getResourceId(1, -1)));
        // Photos
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[2], navMenuIcons
                .getResourceId(2, -1)));
        // Communities, Will add a counter here
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[3], navMenuIcons
                .getResourceId(3, -1), true, "22"));
        // Pages
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[4], navMenuIcons
                .getResourceId(4, -1)));
        // What's hot, We will add a counter here
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[5], navMenuIcons
                .getResourceId(5, -1), true, "50+"));

        // Recycle the typed array
        navMenuIcons.recycle();

        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());

        // setting the nav drawer list adapter
        adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
                navDrawerItems);
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

        // enabling action bar app icon and behaving it as toggle button
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                R.drawable.menu1, // nav menu toggle icon
                R.string.app_name, // nav drawer open - description for
                                    // accessibility
                R.string.app_name // nav drawer close - description for
                                    // accessibility
        ) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        if (savedInstanceState == null)
        {
            // on first time display view for first nav item
            displayView(0);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Slide menu item click listener
     * */
    private class SlideMenuClickListener implements
            ListView.OnItemClickListener 
            {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            // display view for selected nav drawer item
            displayView(position);
        }
    }

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
    {
        // toggle nav drawer on selecting action bar app icon/title
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) 
        {
            return true;
        }
        // Handle action bar actions click
        switch (item.getItemId())
        {
        case R.id.action_settings:
            return true;
        case R.id.logout:

            startActivity(new Intent(this,Login_Activity.class));
            return true;
        case R.id.profile:
            return true;
        case R.id.abouts:
            //startActivity(new Intent(this,About_us.class));
            return true;
        case R.id.changepassword:
            return true;        
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        // Inflating the current activity's menu with
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

    //  getActionBar();
         ActionBar b=getActionBar();

         b.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.SteelBlue)));
         getActionBar().setIcon(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent)));
         //two more option to set bckcolor
         //bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#0000ff")));
          // b.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(0x3366FF));


        // Getting the actionprovider associated with the menu item whose id is
        // share
        // mshareactioprovider=(ShareActionProvider)menu.findItem(R.id.newshare).getActionProvider();

        // Setting a share intent
        // mshareactioprovider.setShareIntent(getDefaultShareIntent());
        // Log.d("MainMenu", ",menu title0: " + menu.getItem(0).getTitle());
        // returns "New Form"
        // menu.addSubMenu(0, Menu.NONE, 1, "Form 1").setIcon(R.drawable.share
        // );
        // menu.addSubMenu(0, Menu.NONE, 2, "Form 2").setIcon(R.drawable.share);
        return true;
    }

        private Intent getDefaultShareIntent() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.setType("text/plain");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "SUBJECT");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Extra Text");
        return intent;

    }

    /* *
     * Called when invalidateOptionsMenu() is triggered
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // if nav drawer is opened, hide the action items
        final boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(drawerll);
        // boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    /**
     * Diplaying fragment view for selected nav drawer list item
     * */
    private void displayView(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            fragment = new HomeFragment();
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new CurrentOpening();
            break;
        case 2:
             fragment = new  Client_Fragment();
            break;
        case 3:
            System.out.println("Submit fragment is called");
            fragment = new Submit_resume();
            break;
        case 4:
            fragment = new About_us();
            break;
        case 5:
            fragment = new Contact_us();
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }

        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.frame_container1, fragment).commit();

            // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
            setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(drawerll);
        } else {
            // error in creating fragment
            Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        mTitle = title;
        getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    }

    /**
     * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
     * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
     */

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
            getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }





}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change below line:

**From**

```
 spinner=(Spinner)container.findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
```

**To**

```
spinner=(Spinner)rootView.findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
```

**Reason:** You need to bind your UI widgets with your **fragment view** not with **Viewgroup**.

**Done**